# Null Lookup column getting from REST API with Expand it give no key for expanded column

Tags: sharepoint-online, rest, lookup-column

I am using REST API to for getting data from SharePoint.

I have one list like category with three column `Title` and two lookup name like `childcategory`, `parentcategory`.

I have some data in which there is no value in both lookup child and parent category.

now I fire query to fetch data expanding lookup value with its Title and ID.

so I'm getting data but in some data of lookup where I didn't get  any key value for expanded title and ID

Response I get like below :

```
"ChildCategory":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/_api/Web/Lists(guid'156456416')/Items(6)/ChildCategory"}}
```

and in some row  have data in lookup that data in response look like this:

```
"SubCategory":{"__deferred":{"uri":"https://xyz.sharepoint.com/sites/abc/_api/Web/Lists(guid'156456416')/Items(8)/SubCategory"},
Title:"abc",
ID:10}
```

so now how can I parse this json.??

because if I am trying to get Value using Key like Title. so it give JSONException because in some data it don't have that key like first which I have posted response.

How to solve this problem?

Any help greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I am checked using JsonObject.has("KeyName") it return boolean.**

**its give true if object contain that keyvalue.**

so using this method you can make your logic.

Thank you very much for reply.

Answer (score 0):

It seems `ChildCategory` and `SubCategory` are not required column. So at the time of parsing your JSON, you need a condition.

```
if(ChildCategory.Title && ChildCategory.ID){

}
```

Another option can be `$filter`. Just `$filter` `null` values for `ID` and `Title` so that they do not appear in the result.

```
&$filter=ChildCategory/Title ne null and ChildCategory/ID ne null
```

Comment: sir in json parsing if i am trying to  getString using Title. then it give exception for it.if there is not value for title in subcategory. i have one solution to handle that exception .but without it. there is any option in sharepoint if lookup column null then i get value like title="null"  ID="null" which we get when text column null. same is possible in lookup.?

Comment: Even in Android development you should **not, never, nimmer, nooit** parse JSON results as if they are Strings. Learn about ``JSON.parse`` and ``hasOwnProperty``. Atish his answer works because checking for a non-existing property returns ``undefined``, which is a FALSE value.

Comment: There is no way to get values like `title="null" ID="null"`. It's better to use `$filter` for `null` values. That means null values will not appear in the result.

Comment: @AtishDipongkor i want  that record title if there lookup null then

Comment: Then you have to consider condition. Another question. What are you using to parse JSON  javascript or JAVA? @AndroidDeveloper

Comment: How did you solve it? If using mine, then accept this answer. Otherwise please add your own answer.  @AndroidDeveloper

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when checking a person field to see it was not empty. Looking for Title didn't work for me. I tried to see if "__deferred" didn't exist and that DID work. Once I getting it working, I don't ask why and just move on. I'll leave that to someone smarter than me.

```js
if (!(ChildCategory.hasOwnProperty('__deferred'))) { 
    alert('result is not empty');
}
```